# geo Query replicating from ruby to Ecto Elixir

Tags: ruby, elixir, geo, ecto

In Ruby I have this function `query.by_distance` where as `by_distance` is something like

```
  def_dataset_method(:by_distance) do |from, meters|
    point = Geocoding.as_point(from)
    query = "ST_DWithin(location, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(?, ?), 4326)::geography, ?)"
    where(query, point.lng, point.lat, meters)
  end
```

in a ruby endpoint user is passing 2 values which are `is_near_to` which is mostly name of a city or a country.. Through which `Geecoding` is getting its points and 2 value is `within_distance` which are `meters` for getting cameras within this `distance`.

The above is happening in Ruby.

What am doing in Elixir to replicate it is

```
  def by_distance(query, is_near_to, within_distance) do
    [%{"lat" => lat, "lng" => lng}] = fetch(is_near_to)
    latitude = lat
    longitude = lng
    query
    |> where([cam], st_dwithin(cam.location, st_set_srid(st_point_from_text(^"#{latitude},#{longitude}"), 4326), ^within_distance))
  end
```

for getting lat and long am doing something as

```
defmodule EvercamMedia.Geocode do

  def fetch(address) do
    response = HTTPotion.get "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=#{URI.encode(address)}&sensor=false"

    {:ok, results} = Poison.decode response.body

    get_in(results, ["results", Access.all(), "geometry", "location"])
  end
end
```

now I have same scenarios. I have both values `is_near_to` and `within_distance`. But am totally unaware of this that how I can replicate the same thing in a query as we are using [`geo`](https://hexdocs.pm/geo/api-reference.html) in our project and by the docs its clearly possible but am not getting the way how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of an app I'm working on, I believe it does what you need, it uses a fragment to pass the ST_distance_sphere call directly to postgis.

Using the library https://github.com/bryanjos/geo and postgis

In the **model**

```
def near_by(query, point, distance) do
  from place in query,
  where: fragment("ST_distance_sphere(?,?)", place.location, ^point) >= ^distance,
  order_by: fragment("ST_distance_sphere(?,?)", place.location, ^point),
  select: {place, fragment("ST_distance_sphere(?,?)", place.location, ^point)}
end
```

In the **controller**

```
def near_by(conn, %{"latitude" => latitude, "longitude" => longitude, "distance" => distance}) do
  point = %Geo.Point{coordinates: {String.to_float(latitude), String.to_float(longitude)}, srid: 4326}
  places = Place
  |> Place.near_by(point, String.to_float(distance))
  |> Repo.all
  render(conn, "near_by.json", places: places)
end
```

In the **view**

```
def render("near_by_place.json", %{place: place}) do
  { place, distance } = place
  {lat, lon} = place.location.coordinates
  %{id: place.id,
    name: place.name,
    latitude: lat,
    longitude: lon,
    distance: distance}
end
```